# How to put a lambda with external parameters into a callback function

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, callback

I have the following code which basically does what I want:

```
string firstName = "Chuck";
string lastName = "Norris";

 filtered = dvds.Where(
            dvd => (dvd.Element("Actors") != null) && (dvd.Element("Actors").Elements("Actor").Where(
                actor => actor.Attribute("FirstName") != null && actor.Attribute("FirstName").Value == firstName 
                    && actor.Attribute("LastName") != null && actor.Attribute("LastName").Value == lastName)).Count() > 0);
```

As you can see, the lambda is quite big. I'd rather have a callback method in the first .Where call. But I don't see how I could give the firstName and lastName parameters into that callback method.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just pass a method to the first `Where`, since you also need to pass the first and last names, but you can pass a simpler lambda... Here's a possible refactoring:

```
filtered = dvds.Where(dvd => HasActor(dvd, firstName, lastName));
...

bool HasActor(XElement dvd, string firstName, string lastName)
{
    var actors = dvd.Element("Actors");
    if (actors != null)
    [
        var actor = actor.FirstOrDefault(a => IsActor(a, firstName, lastName));
        return actor != null;
    }
    return false;
}

bool IsActor(XElement actor, string firstName, string lastName)
{
    string firstNameAttr = actor.Attribute("FirstName");
    string lastNameAttr = actor.Attribute("LastName");
    return firstNameAttr != null
        && firstNameAttr.Value == firstName
        && lastNameAttr != null
        && lastNameAttr.Value == lastName;
}
```

Comment: *slaps head*

Sometimes you don't see the forest for the trees.

Of course(!) I can just call another method and pass on the additional parameters.

Now I feel stupid. :-/